# Reading attachments from mail using Microsoft exchange web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, exchangewebservices

We have the below code to read the attachments using EWS.

```
     FindItemsResults<Item> foundItems = service.FindItems(FolderId, new ItemView(1000));

    var orderItems = from list in foundItems
                     orderby list.DateTimeReceived
                     select list;
    foreach (EmailMessage item in orderItems)
    {
        item.Load();//SARANYA
        EmailMessage foundEmail = (EmailMessage)item;
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(item.Id.ToString()), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.Body));
        if (message.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            FileAttachment[] attachments = null;
            attachments = new FileAttachment[message.Attachments.Count];

            foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                    {

                        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
                        //   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                        fileAttachment.Load();
                        byte[] FolloupMailFileAttachmentContentBytes = fileAttachment.Content;
                        bool isScreenshot = false;
                        string ScreenfileName = "";

                        for (int i = 0; i < imgSrcs.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (imgSrcs[i].ToString() == fileAttachment.Name.ToString())
                            {
                                isScreenshot = true;
                                if (!imgSrcs[i].ToString().Contains(".png"))
                                    ScreenfileName = "cid:" + imgSrcs[i].ToString() + ".png";
                                else
                                    ScreenfileName = "cid:" + imgSrcs[i].ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (FolloupMailFileAttachmentContentBytes != null)
                        {
                            if (isScreenshot && RemoveSuccess == 1)
                            {
                                InsertMailItemAttachment(ScreenfileName, FolloupMailFileAttachmentContentBytes, caseid);
                            }
                            else
                                InsertMailItemAttachment(fileAttachment.Name.ToString(), FolloupMailFileAttachmentContentBytes, caseid);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (attachment is ItemAttachment)
                    {
                        item.Move(unreadmailFolder.Id);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exe)
                {
                    if (!ReadMoved)
                    {
                        item.Move(readmailFolder.Id);
                        ReadMoved = true;
                    }
                    logfile.HandleError(exe, "Attachment Exception \n\nEmailbox - " + EMailBox + "\n\nEmail Subject - " + strSubject + " \n - Could not load the attachment (" + attachment.Name.ToString() + ")");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code is working when I provide thread.sleep() before fileattachment.load(). when thread.sleep is removed, I get the below exception.

```
  Error Source        : Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
Target Site         :   Void InternalThrowIfNecessary()
System Message      :   The specified object was not found in the store.
Stack Trace         :      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.ThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalGetAttachments(IEnumerable`1 attachments, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAttachment(Attachment attachment, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment.InternalLoad(Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment.Load()
   at EMT_Office365_MailFetch_Scheduler.Program.FindEmail(Object threadState) in
```

Experts, Please provide your valuable inputs

Comment: Please format your code so it becomes more readable

Comment: I have formatted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't look correct eg

```
 item.Move(unreadmailFolder.Id);
```

Should not be inside the Foreach loop if you want to move the message at the end just use a Flag and process it once you have finished processing the attachments(you logic doesn't work if you have two ItemAttachment this would execute twice). The reason sleep is working is mostly likely an Aysnc operation is completing once you have executed the move. Thats why this should be outside of the foreach attachment loop

Comment: Hi Glen, you are right. the logic in item attachment is incorrect, I will have it corrected. that part of the code is never executed as our mails doesnot contain any item attachment. My query is about the file attachment portion where when I introduce a sleep, the attachments are read, but when it is removed, I get an error. we don't have any async operation in our logic. I was wondering if this has anything to do with permission etc, but as it works with sleep, I ruled out that option also.

Comment: However we have different threads process different mailboxes. does that have any impact?

Comment: If you had multiple threads working on the same item then yes you have potential for conflicting updates.